# How to display text from a dropdown in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a partial view that has to display records on the change of dropdown. The values are coming correctly but it is not being displayed in the tex boxes. Please help. THe code of my partial view looks like below

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("W2State", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "model", OnSuccess = "w2Updated", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "Post" } ))
{

    <fieldset id="currencyView" class="detailView">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 100px;">Select Agency </td> 
                <td> 
                @*@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ReportingAgencies, new SelectList(Model.ReportingAgencies, "SelectedAgency.AgencyGuid", "SelectedAgency.Name"), new { id = "dropDownReportAgencies" })*@
               @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ReportingAgencies, new SelectList(Model.ReportingAgencies, "SelectedAgency.AgencyGuid", "SelectedAgency.Name"), "--Select An Agency--", new { id = "dropDownReportAgencies" })
                </td>              
            </tr>
            <tr class="seperator"></tr>
            <tr class="seperator"></tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="width: 100px;">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.W2StateLocal.Wages)</td> 
                <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.W2StateLocal.Wages)</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 100px;">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.W2StateLocal.Tax)</td> 
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.W2StateLocal.Tax)</td> 
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="rightButtonControls">        
            @if (Model.IsEditable)
            {
                <button id="btnSave" value="save">Save</button>                
            }
        </div>    
    </fieldset>
}

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CompanyId, new { id = "CompanyId" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmployeeId, new { id = "EmployeeId" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FilingYear, new { id = "FilingYear" })


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#divLoader").css('display', 'none');
        $('#dropDownReportAgencies').change(function () {

            var selectedAgency = $('#dropDownReportAgencies option:selected').val();


            var CompanyId = $('#CompanyId').val();

            var EmployeeId = $('#EmployeeId').val();

            var FilingYear = $('#FilingYear').val();

            var url = '@Url.Action("W2State", "W2Generation")';
            $.get(url, { agencyId: selectedAgency, companyId: CompanyId, employeeId: EmployeeId, filingYear: FilingYear },
                function (data) {
                            });



        });

    });
```

Comment: Is the code being loaded in the drop down lists and not the text boxes?  Can you give a little more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get text from dropdown in mvc through jQuery...

Your code is right but just missing something.. You used

```
var selectedAgency = $('#dropDownReportAgencies option:selected').val();
```

but instead of 'val' you have to use 'text'.. it means

```
var selectedAgency = $("#dropDownReportAgencies option:selected").text();
```

Try this....